# Possible methods of input for languages with a lot of diacritic characters

Tags: written-language, writing-systems, diacritics

I'm afraid this question may be closed as off topic, but I am struggling to find a more applicable stack to ask this in.

I am in the very early stages of studying Babylonian, and I am struggling with how to type the normalised text as it contains a lot of diacritic characters, for example:

> upaššišū, upaṭṭirā

At present I have some auto-correct rules setup to correct a'm to ā (I actually use backtick rather than an apostrophe but Stack doesn't like it), but this only works when the a'm is a separate word, so it really breaks the flow of typing; and hence comprehension.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: You can make your own custom keyboard layout with extra letter + diacritic combos assigned to keys with shift / alt / alt-gr, etc. Or you can add what are called "dead keys" for the diacritics, which means you type those letters with two keypresses. This is unrelated to whether there are precomposed or use combining characters in Unicode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to [create your own keyboard layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) (it applies if you use MS Windows, or just google the phrase for other platforms). You can use Latvian keyboard layout as a base, it already has **š** and vowel letters with macrons (like **ā** and **ū**). You'll only have to define the keys for the letters with the under-dot, like **ṭ**, and for **ḫ**.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you - I'll start Googling how I do this for my OS.

Comment: Yet another layout with lots of typography symbols. May become a great starting point, Mac/Windows: [details and download](http://ilyabirman.net/projects/typography-layout/)